# RSpec Example - Tennis Soccer class

Tags: ruby, tdd, rspec2

In the book "Programming Ruby 1.9/2.0" the author gives an example of a Tennis Scorer class that will be developed by writing some RSpec tests before the actual code.

The author introduces 4 tests:

```
it "should start with a score of 0-0"
it "should be 15-0 if the server wins a point"
it "should be 0-15 if the receiver wins a point"
it "should be 15-15 after they both win a point"
```

and then the author suggests that the reader should go ahead and complete the class by writing tests like this:

```
it "should be 40-0 after the server wins three points"
it "should be W-L after the server wins four points"
it "should be L-W after the receiver wins four points"
it "should be Deuce after each wins three points"
it "should be A-server after each wins three points and the server gets one more"
```

(The actual TennisScorer Class adds scores for each player and returns them in a format like "15-15").

Does the author assume that the code will work 100% for scores like 30-15, 15-30, 0-30, 30-0, and so forth as long as the test succeeds for 15-0, 0-15, and 15-15? In other words, it's not necessary to test for each possible score explicitly?
The author suggests a 40-0 test, which makes sense because 40 breaks the 0-15-30 convention (score * 15), so does a 40-0 test suffice to show that 40-30, 15-40, etc will work as well?

Also, maybe I'm overcomplicating this, but wouldn't it make more sense to have a "random game" in my test where I add random scores 100000 times and compare the outcome dynamically? (but I guess then my test could contain some bugs easily..?).
I figure that this would be the way to go if I would write a test for a multiplication method for example (or would I then just check if 1*2 = 2 and assume that everything works fine?)

Answer (score 0):

The point with tdd is to have your specs and code grow over time in small increments. So you are supposed to start out with some simple things exactly as outlined above. However as your spec suite grows as well as your code you will feel the need to refactor both the code and the specs. This is natural and as it should be. I would expect the code inside one of your *its* to be a one line call to a generic method that takes input to the method under test and the expected outcome. At least that is the place I often end up at.

With the spec above the code may not work with 30-15 etc as you are pointing out. It depends on how the the implementation turns out. It would make sense to add some more specs here and reuse the test code beneath.

I would recommend against having randomized specs in most cases because you can't guarantee the outcome. If the code itself has random behavior it may make sense though. I would try to isolate the randomness to one place so that the rest can be tested deterministically.